# SQL Access: Recent date per ID

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have four tables: User, Version, VersionOfDocument, Document.
The ER looks like this: (bold = primary key)
[image: ...]

I want the query to show for each documentID the most recent date, versionNr and the person who made the last change of the document:

```
documentID          modifiedDate    Username                  VersionNr
1                   1/4/2014        Alfred.Heymans@test.nl     2.0
2                   2/5/2013        Alfred.Heymans@test.nl     1.0
3                   4/5/2014        John.Smith@test.nl         2.0
```

Comment: Is it mysql or access? Can't be both

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT VD.DocumentID, V.modifiedDate, U.Username, V.VersionNr
FROM VersionOfDocument VD 
INNER JOIN VERSION V ON VD.VersonId = V.VersionId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT VD.DocumentID, MAX(V.modifiedDate) modifiedDate
            FROM VersionOfDocument VD 
            INNER JOIN VERSION V ON VD.VersonID = V.VersionID 
            GROUP BY VD.DocumentID
           ) AS A ON VD.DocumentID = A.DocumentID AND V.modifiedDate = A.modifiedDate 
INNER JOIN USER U ON V.userID = U.userID;
```

Comment: Why did you change the tag of the question? Can you be 100% sure that it is mysql not access? When the title is SQL Access: Recent date per ID

Comment: I get a Syntax error (missing operator): [image](http://i.imgur.com/YlmXB4s.jpg?1?3870)